# How to start the 'vmmon' kernel module in Mac? VMware Fusion fails to start VM after inactivity

Tags: vmware

So if I don't open up a VM in awhile and decide to finally start one up, VMware Fusion tells me that it cannot load the kernel module 'vmmon'. I usually always have to restart my system to fix this problem, but that's becoming very annoying. My workaround in the recent past has been just to let a VM stay open and leave it running in the background.

Does anyone actually know a way to fix this without rebooting? Most of the support sites that I see answering this question just suggest running something in the terminal and rebooting, which appears to be just a temporary fix and unnecessary as rebooting alone temporarily fixes it.